# Can i use a view or viewmodel from a optional package in my main project with C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, package

does someone know if is possible use a view and a viewmodel from a optional package in my main project? . I need modularize my app including code, views and viewmodels. All that in C# if it possible. Where can i find documentation about that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) to use an Inversion of Control pattern.